# Rest standards for retrieving by external id

Tags: list, rest, get

I need to design a new api and I would like to collect arguments and find the best approach. What are the RESt recommendations for my situation?

We have an object

```
class Product {
      int id // id generated by our system
      string externalId // unique id sent by the client
      date creationDateTime
      string type;
}
```

Of course we will implement a get endpoint for the id field:

`GET /products/{productId}`

But also I know that the clients would like to have a search by the externalId (which is unique) and the type/date.

What is better from the design perpective for the external id search:

to have a get endpoint

`GET /products/externalId/{externalId}`

or to have a **list** endpoint (which can be extendable to type and dateTime filters) that will return a list of one object

`GET /products/?externalId={externalId}`

? Do we have any REST standards for this? Please, share the facts and citations if you have.

Thanks.`

Answer (score 2):

> Do we have any REST standards for this?

No.

[REST](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

The HTTP specification says (currently [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-identifiers-in-http)) says that we should be using uniform resource identifiers (currently [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html)).

It's convenient, but not required, to choose resource identifiers that are readily described by URI Templates ([RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570.html)).

Using path segments is convenient when you want to use [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-5.2.4) to describe the spelling of one identifier relative to another.

Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded key/value pairs in the query part is convenient when you want to use HTML forms.

```
/products/externalId/{externalId}
/products/?externalId={externalId}
```

Note that, while the alternatives might have equivalent semantics in your resource model, as far as the web is concerned, these are different resource identifiers, and general purpose components SHOULD treat them as different things (ex: web caches should have an entry for each, and invalidating one entry should not affect the other).